# Rails 3 logout route in sessions controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have methodically been working thru the Agile Web Development with Rails book.  No problems so far until I came across the development of logout using the sessions controller.  I am simply trying to get the destroy method to work in the session controller.  Here is what I have:

sessions_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
   redirect_to store_url, :notice => "Logged out"
end
```

routes.rb

```
controller :sessions do
  get  'login' => :new
  post 'login' => :create
  delete 'logout' => :destroy
end
```

I reset the server and can login using localhost:3000/login  BUT if i try localhost:3000/logout i get the following routing error:  No route matches "/logout"

Any help is greatly appreciated as I have been digging thru the web trying to find a answer.

Comment: Can you show the code for the logout link in your view too? Maybe it's missing `:method => :delete`?

Comment: Austin is correct. When you enter `/logout` in your browser directly, you are doing a `get` request, whereas a `delete` request is expected. If you want to be able to logout by entering `/logout` in the address bar of your browser, you have to change `delete` to `get`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe

```
delete 'logout' => :destroy
```

should be

```
get 'logout' => :destroy
```

or

```
post 'logout' => :destroy
```

depending on how you are handling the behavior. Most likely you want `get`.

Comment: No, logout destroy the session, so a delete request is correct.

Comment: yes the action itself is a destroy action because you are destroying the session. However to rails, when the user goes to /logout they are performing a get request.

Comment: I see your point now... he is not talking about a link, but just going to /logout directly. If you edit your answer a little bit, I can undo my downvote. Sorry...

Comment: If he wants to logout by typing `/logout` in the address bar of the browser, I agree you could use `get`, but I don't see how you would ever you `post` here. Anyway I edited your answer so I could undo my downvote. Hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: Thanks worked.  I'm wondering if that is just a typo in AWDWR (Fourth Edition) depot_r/config/routes.rb

Answer (score 1):

OK NO TYPO in AWDWR.  The code/route provided by the original question is correct if you wish to execute the following button:

```
<%= button_to 'Logout', logout_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Not sure why this works for the button but the "get" answer works when I type /logout in the URL??

Answer (score 1):

This is because the browsers only support two HTTP verbs: GET and POST. Rails uses tricks (JavaScript - I think) to pretend the browsers are sending "PUT" and "DELETE", which would be routed to associate with different actions to those of GET and POST. In the above case, DELETE method is routed to the controller's destroy action, with the sole purpose of close a session but not rendering pages.

In config/route.rb - the following is the key for the logout button click:

```
controller :sessions do
    get 'login' => :new
    post 'login' => :create
    delete 'logout' => :destroy
end
```